# Python - generating weight map in C4D

Tags: python, 3d, cinema-4d

Hello Python and Stack community in general.

First, let me say I'm a 3d guy and not much of a code guy. So thanks for the understanding...

The exact problem:
I have to generate a gradient map based on a distance from points to **multiple objects**

Here is a simple preview of what my problem looks like 
[Preview_C4D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GU0X.jpg)

My base code is the following:

```html
import c4d
#Welcome to the world of Python
warray = [0.0]
def main():
    global warray
    wtag = op[c4d.ID_USERDATA,1]  #drag vertex map from user data panel
    obj = wtag.GetObject()    #the object of the vertex map
    pts = obj.GetAllPoints()
    cnt = len(pts)
    null = op.GetObject()
    nullpos =  null.GetMg().off  #vector magnitude from matrix
    minDistance = op[c4d.ID_USERDATA,4]  #drag slider map from user data panel
    maxDistance = op[c4d.ID_USERDATA,5]  #drag slider map from user data panel
   
    
    if len(warray) != cnt:
        diff = cnt - len(warray)
        warray.extend([0.0]*diff)
    
    for  x in xrange(cnt): #remapping in the range 0-1
        point = pts[x]
        distance = (nullpos - point).GetLength()
        warray[x] = c4d.utils.RangeMap(distance,minDistance,maxDistance,1,0,False)
        if warray[x] > 1:
            warray[x] = 1.0
        elif warray[x] < 0:
            warray[x] = 0.0
    wtag.SetAllHighlevelData(warray)  #bake the new vertex map
```

Now lets say I have a list with multiple objects:

```html
parent = doc.SearchObject('parent')
    
    
    list1 = parent.GetChildren() # list of cubes under parent
    count = len(list1)
    for a in range(list):
      obj = list1[a]
      distance = ?
```

So I'm stuck here, because I can't figure it out how to merge 
the new values with the old.
In few words I need a loop that evaluates the values for the points
for each object in the list and then adds them toghether.
I just can't dial it up right.

So I'll be very grateful if anybody can help.

Regards